# Error BulkCopy with C# - Oracle.DataAccess.Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlbulkcopy

I have long field in my table. When I make the copies by bulkcopy the following message appears.

ORA-26089: LONG column "CORPO_EMAIL" must be specified last

I do not understand the reason for this error. Is there any special configuration I need to do for this column in a DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the issue you need to specify the LONG column ie, CORPO_EMAIL at the last.

The cause of this error is that a client of the direct path API specified a LONG column to be loaded, but the LONG column was not the last column to be specified.

Also check [How to solve Error Code ORA-26089](http://www.oracle-error.com/10g/ORA-26089.html).